# Trouble Deriving the Canonical Commutation Relation from the Product Rule

Tags: complex-analysis, quantum-mechanics

From pg. 74 of  *No-Nonsense Quantum Mechanics*, the author derives the **canonical commutation relation** from the momentum operator $\hat{p}_i$ as follows:

> [image]

**Question:** How does the **product rule** (for complex derivatives, which I assume is what the author is referring to) imply that

$$
(-i \hslash \partial_i \hat{x}_j + \hat{x}_j i \hslash )  | \Psi\rangle $$

equals

$$
-(i \hslash \partial_i \hat{x}_j) | \Psi \rangle - \hat{x}_j (i \hslash \partial_i | \Psi \rangle) + \hat{x}_j i \hslash \partial_i | \Psi \rangle
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
-i \hslash \partial_i \hat{x}_j |\Psi\rangle
= -i \hslash \partial_i (\hat{x}_j |\Psi\rangle)
= -i \hslash \partial_i (x_j |\Psi\rangle) \\
= \{ \text{ product rule on factors $x_j$ and $|\Psi\rangle$ } \} \\
= -i \hslash ((\partial_i x_j) |\Psi\rangle) + x_j (\partial_i |\Psi\rangle)
$$